# How to use created sub folder in public folder on Play Framework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework-2.2, scala-2.10

I created "xlsfiles" subfolder in public folder, and I used it folder for create xls file by request.

[image]

And when user send request to server to get this xls file I serve this file to client.

When I run project on Dev Mode all working perfectly, but when I run project on Production Mode not exist "xlsfiles" subfolder and I get "FileNotFoundException" exception.

Have any solution? How to make create sub folder in the project and create file in it?

Comment: Ok. Maybe I didn't understand your question. Are you creating those files dynamically at runtime? Or are they static? Are you using Assets controller to get path to those files? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Assets

Comment: I create xls files at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Use Files class from standard Play framework API:

[http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Files$](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Files%24)